# Excel encoding throw connection

Tags: excel, utf-8, connection-string, cyrillic

I have mondrian server, which response with utf-8 xml document with cyrillic characters. I'm connecting to it via xmla connect. All works fine, except cyrillic characters.
Is there any way to set excel to recognize my characters?

Comment: What are the results so far...?

Answer (score 0):

It was new XMLA connect fault. I downgraded it and utf-8 working just fine, at least v1.0.0.5. Also it solved problem with dimensions on row and on column: I wasn't able to use both rows and columns for two dimensions, now, on old version, it all works great.